# Need to print an author of a book by the book's title

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I don't know how to print the author of a book by inputting the book's title. The book and its author are separated from each other by a pipe character ("|")  in the text file. I only found out how to print first book's author.

```
def load_library(a):
    s = open(a,'r')
    while True:
        theline = s.readline()
        razdel = theline.split('|')
        if len(theline) == 0:
            break
        books_authors=razdel.pop(1)
        return books_authors
    return razdel
    s.close()

if __name__=='__main__':
    result = load_library('books.txt')
    print(result)
```

Comment: Would a dictionary mapping book to author suffice as a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns the call inside the while loop instead of printing/saving it to a list. So only the first line is read.

```
def load_library(a):
   s = open(a,'r')
   result = []
   while True:
            theline = s.readline()
            razdel = theline.split('|')
            if len(theline) == 0:
                break
            books_authors=razdel.pop(1)
            result.append(book_authors)
   s.close()
   return result




if __name__=='__main__':
    result = load_library('books.txt')
    print(result)
```

Comment: Need just one author of inputing book's title, not all the authors

Comment: can you mention more about the format of data in books.txt?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your text file is sorted in the form booktitle |  author, this sould do it.

```
import csv

#read csv sheet into dict
D={}
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    fcsv=csv.reader(f,delimiter='|')
    for row in fcsv:
        D[row[0]]=row[1]

print D[booktitle]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `'books.txt'` file contained these entries:

```
Title1|Joe Blow
Title2|Jane Doe
Title Number Three|Henry Longwords
```

You could build a dictionary from it that had the book title as the keys and a list of author(s) that wrote it. Here's what I I'm talking about:

```
from pprint import pprint

def load_library(filename):
    authors_by_book = {}
    with open(filename) as file:
       for line in file:
           author, title = line.strip().split('|')
           authors_by_book.setdefault(author, []).append(title)

    return authors_by_book


if __name__=='__main__':
    authors_by_book = load_library('books.txt')
    pprint(authors_by_book)
    print()
    print('Author(s) of {}: {}'.format('Title2', authors_by_book['Title2']))
```

Output:

```
{'Title Number Three': ['Henry Longwords'],
 'Title1': ['Joe Blow'],
 'Title2': ['Jane Doe']}

Author(s) of Title2: ['Jane Doe']
```

The reason the value associated with each key is a list, is because a book could have more than one author. This could happen if the same title appeared more than once in the `'bookts.txt'` file, like this:

```
Deep Throat|Bob Woodward
Deep Throat|Carl Bernstein
```

You could modify the code to support having multiple authors listed in a single entry, such as:

```
Deep Throat|Bob Woodward|Carl Bernstein
```

if you needed/wanted to.

Comment: Yeah, that works. Thanks, man! But what if I also have the same txt file, but now I need to find all books of the given author. How to write this reversed program?

Comment: @Kapa: To find all the books by a given author, you could construct a second dictionary named `books_by_author` and create it in a way similar to what's currently in my answer only with `author` and `title` specified in the opposite order.